# Load and use XGBoost PMML or XGBoost .rds model in python sklearn with out loosing its dependencies/nature

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, xgboost, pmml

I have a XGB model which is built in R, I wanted to use the same model in python for predictions without loosing its nature/embedded dependencies.

I've tried rpy2 and sklearn-pmml-model, seems there is no help for XGBoost models.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PyPMML](https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml) to evaluate XGBoost PMML in Python, for example:

```
from pypmml import Model

model = Model.fromFile('the/pmml/model/file/path')
result = predict(data)
```

The `data` could be in dict, Series or DataFrame of Pandas, or JSON string.